# IntelliJ and JavaFX on MacOs Big Sur

Tags: java, intellij-idea, javafx, javafx-8, macos-big-sur

Trying to launch my code on IntelliJ but my Mac (Big Sur) blocks libprism_es2.dylib and libjavafx_font.dylib because they are not verified. Bypassing with "Open anyway" from settings doesn't work.

How can i solve ?

Comment: did you see this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60934986/how-to-run-java-from-macos-catalina-build-10-15-4 ? It might be as simple as some old version hanging around .. (not on mac, just did use the search field - as you should have ;)

Answer (score 0):

Use xattr:

In Terminal, type the following

```
sudo xattr -d com.apple.quarantine com.apple.FinderInfo path/to/the/dylibs/lib*.dylib
```

Then enter ur admin passcode, and wait a bit because it takes  a minute or 2.